# Setting linkedList node to None does not clear the parent link

Tags: python

Within my linkedList, here is how I implemented the deletion method.

```
def remove(self,key):
        if self.head is None:
            return

        z = self.head

        while (z.key != key and z.next is not None):
            z = z.next


        if (z.key == key):
            if z.next is None:
                z = None 
            else:
                z.key = z.next.key
                z.value = z.next.value
                z.next = z.next.next

            self.size -= 1
```

The problem that I encounter is that if the node z does not have a next, its set to none. But the following code

```
w = LinkedList("A",5)
w.append("B", 7)
w.append("C",10)
w.remove("C")
```

will at the end print out `A, B, C`. The expected behavior here would be for A, and B to be printed. Why does setting z to none, not set the parent nodes reference of that node to None as welL?

Comment: Would you expect `a=[]; b=a; b=None` to somehow change `a` to `None` that is what you are suggesting. You have to explicitly set the `parent.next` to `z.next`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your deletion method is wrong, setting the current node's values with next node's values would not work (it would duplicate the next node) .

Also, setting `z` local variable to `None` would not have any effect on the actual linked list.

What you have to do for deletion is to iterate till the node whose next node has same `key` and the set that node's next to point the next node's next. Example -

```
def remove(self,key):
    if self.head is None:
        return
    if self.head.key == key:
        self.head = self.head.next
        return        
    z = self.head
    while z.next is not None and z.next.key != key:
        z = z.next

    if (z.next.key == key):
        z.next = z.next.next
        self.size -= 1
```

Comment: What happens if the Node's next is None?

Comment: if `z.next.next` is None, meaning the key was found at last node, it would set `B` node's next as `none` making that the last node.

Comment: Ahhh, I now see that your testing the Nodes next, but there would need to be special handling if the head is the only node and it doesn't have a next. Also, why don't local variables affect the actual linkedList?

Comment: because they are local variables? Local to the function, they get destroyed when the function exits.

Comment: The issue I have with the above answer is that if head is the only node and it is the key, you won't ever delete the node at the head.

Comment: Fixed, to accommodate that as well.